# Whats the smartest way to password protect an entire Django site for testing purposes

Tags: python, html, django

Here is the deal, how do I put the simplest password protection on an entire site. I simply want to open the site to beta testing but don't really care about elegance - just a dirty way of giving test users a username and password without recourse to anything complex and ideally i'd like to not to have to install any code or third party solutions. I'm trying to keep this simple.

Comment: Maybe a digest auth using apache or whatever webserver you prefer?

Comment: If you are using apache, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#page-header basic auth should serve your purpose. It is just a setting in the apache config, so you dont have to modify the application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2468/

That is basically what @karthikr suggested, but it relies entirely on Django instead of Apache.

That said, I almost always use Apache (.htaccess) to put up basic Http Auth, because I'm almost always, on Apache, and because it doesn't enter my codebase (which is not really a problem, actually...)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of installable Django apps to handle this for you, and which make it easy to make exceptions ("just allow the public to see one page").

1. [Stronghold](https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold)
2. [Lockdown](https://github.com/Dunedan/django-lockdown)

I've had very good experiences with Stronghold.

Comment: Django Stronghold claims to be compatible for Django v1.8 - v2.2. It also seems to work well with Django 3.2, though you'll need to replace 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' with 'MIDDLEWARE' in your settings during installation if you're running anything newer than Django 1.8. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not do simple form on index page when user is not authenticated?

Comment: Because I have my own authentication system sep from Django

Comment: So still you can display form to login with your auth system, right?

Comment: I used Google users so I don't handle user in Django...hence my question.