# Simple authentication Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django-rest/React project and want to enable simple (hard-coded) login/pass authentication on index page. Only need this authentication to access the page by the user, and don't want to use authetication on rest requests.

Have tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941038/7225171), but in this case all rest API requests return **403 forbidden** responses after entering login/pass credentials.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about creating your own custom decorator to verify if the credentials are passed?

Comment: Can you, please, provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

I use token authentication. It is simple and well described in documentation.
Please look: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: I don't want to use token authentication and go deep into it's details, that's why I wrote on my question: `don't want to use authetication on rest requests`. I just want to simply limit user access to my main (index) page.